# Labelling inputs in HTML: <p>, placeholder or both?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On forms, is inline placeholder text better than a label outside each field?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9220/on-forms-is-inline-placeholder-text-better-than-a-label-outside-each-field)

I am making a simple registration form for my website. I'm in doubt about how to label inputs: should I use text (i.e. Username: next to the input box), the placeholder attribute (like the "search" word *inside* the search bar), or both?

For a graphical example of what I mean, see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dWPan/).
[image]

**HTML5 note**: I'm assuming the user has a browser with support for HTML5. The fallback content will only use labels.

Comment: Are you asking which solution is most usable, or best to implement?

Comment: Does this question cover what you're asking about, or is your question covering something different? http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9220/on-forms-is-inline-placeholder-text-better-than-a-label-outside-each-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is more than accessibility.  **It is mostly about design choices and clarity** for your customers. There are situations where space constraints and very simple forms make a simple placeholder a neater option, but **in most situations it is better to have a label** (although where the label is is another question).

There are accessibility  questions to consider, but there are ways of making each option accessible to screen readers.

For a deeper explanation of this (although a bit old now) read [Web Form Design](http://rosenfeldmedia.com/books/webforms/).

Answer (score 4):

For accessibility and usability, every text input field should have a textual label, associated with it using `label` markup. Using `p` markup is irrelevant to this.

Using `placeholder` is not necessary, and it is pointless (even disturbing) if it only repeats the label.

There is no browser that supports (all of the) HTML5 (drafts).

Comment: I agree. Keep in mind that placeholders may be 100% appropriate as the only label on mobile devices.

Comment: Placeholder is not pointless. There are situations like search bars where it makes more sense to hide the label, and use the placeholder as the key reference for a user. The label remains in the code to be used by screenreaders but hidden from sight, freeing up space. Facebook does exactly this "Search for people, places and things..."